# What do you call words that are separated by a hyphen?

Tags: terminology, hyphenation

What do you call words like *one-note* that are separated by a hyphen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would call them *hyphenated [compounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound)*, as opposed to *solid compounds* and *open compounds*. Note how they are not *dashed*. That's because a [hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) (-) is not the same as a [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) (–, —, ⁓, ‒).

> Short compounds may be written in three different ways, which do not correspond to different pronunciations, however:
>
> - The "solid" or "closed" forms in which two usually moderately short words appear together as one. Solid compounds most likely consist of short (monosyllabic) units that often have been established in the language for a long time. Examples are *housewife*, *lawsuit*, *wallpaper*, etc.
> - The *hyphenated* form in which two or more words are connected by a hyphen. Compounds that contain affixes, such as *house-build(er)* and *single-mind(ed)(ness)*, as well as adjective-adjective compounds and verb-verb compounds, such as *blue-green* and *freeze-dried*, are often hyphenated. Compounds that contain articles, prepositions or conjunctions, such as *rent-a-cop*, *mother-of-pearl* and *salt-and-pepper*, are also often hyphenated.
> - The *open* or *spaced* form consisting of newer combinations of usually longer words, such as *distance learning*, *player piano*, *lawn tennis*, etc.

Comment: [This link](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/042703CompWdsHyph.htm) would give you right.

Comment: Although the OP has accepted this answer, it does not quite answer the question *as formulated*. It sought the term for the words *separated* by the hyphen. On literal reading, that is a question about the *components* of a hyphenated compound, not about the compound as a whole.

Answer (score 4):

The “-” sign is not a dash, but a **hyphen**. Words that contain one or more hyphens are said to be **hyphenated**.

Dashes of various length are used in English writing: “–” is an *en dash*, and “—” is an em dash. Their names (*en* and *em*) are those of typographic units of measurements. The former is used in particular to separate dates in ranges (“Lee, Bruce (1941–73)”), and the latter is used to indicate a break of thought or an unfinished sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the term you are looking for is *hyphenated* words. Note that the hyphen and the dash (or, rather, dashes -- there are several of them) are different characters.