# What is the rule for composing two words, when one of them is hyphenized or has spaces?

Tags: grammar, compounds, acronyms, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Let's imagine we have an organization named EFSMA-EE and another called EFSMA Telecom (EFSMA is an acronym).

If I want to compose these with another word (e.g. "time" - as in "full-time"), what should I do?

Just add the hyphen?

> EFSMA-EE-time and EFSMA Telecom-time?

Comment: I would refer to [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13855/what-do-you-call-words-that-are-separated-by-a-hyphen/13857#13857) to another question which enumarates guideline to create compounds.

Comment: @Eldros: Nothing is told about acronyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usually better to rephrase such constructions. However, if you cannot do this, you can use an en dash instead. Quoting from The Chicago Manual of Style:

> The en dash is used in place of a hyphen in a compound adjective when one of its elements is an open compound or when two or more of its elements are open compounds or hyphenated compounds (e.g., *a quasi-public–quasi-judicial body*, the post–World War II years).

You can write the phrase in your question as

> EFSMA-EE–time and EFSMA Telecom–time

Comment: Per Chicago, I believe the convention is to use the en dash first, hyphen second. EFSMA[en dash]EE-time, etc.

Comment: @The Raven: My interpretation is that the already-hyphenated compound (EFSMA[hyphen]EE) stays hyphenated, and you use the en dash to add the third word, either before or after the term (to do which you would normally use a hyphen). For instance, in _quasi-public–quasi-judicial_, _quasi-public_ and _quasi-judicial_ are both already hyphenated, and the en dash is used to join the two hyphenated terms. If we were saying pre–EFSMA-EE, the en dash would, as you say, be used first. But if we say, EFSMA-EE–time, EFSMA-EE stays hyphenated, and the en dash is used after.